# Populate select option from json result

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm trying to populate option for my selectbox. Here is what i do

**create-ticket.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MainproviderProvider } from '../../providers/mainprovider/mainprovider';

/**
 * Generated class for the CreateTicketPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-create-ticket',
  templateUrl: 'create-ticket.html',
})
export class CreateTicketPage {
  responseData : any;
  objectKeys = Object.keys;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public MainproviderProvider : MainproviderProvider) {

 }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.MainproviderProvider.populateprobParent().then((result) => { 
            this.responseData = result;
         });
  }

}
```

and here is my **create-ticket.html**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>CreateTicket</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


    <ion-content padding>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="this.responseData" [required]="true" [name]="value">
            <ion-option *ngFor="let option of objectKeys(value)">
                {{ value[ProblemId] }} - {{ value[ProblemDesc] }}
            </ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-content>
```

but when i run it, i get this error

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

and here is my json looks like

```
{"parentData": [{"ProblemId":"PROB001","ProblemParent":null,"ProblemDesc":"Masalah Jaringan"},{"ProblemId":"PROB005","ProblemParent":null,"ProblemDesc":"Masalah Komputer"}]}
```

Did i miss something ? how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ngFor over the response data

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="select" [required]="true" [name]="value">
            <ion-option *ngFor="let optionObj of responseData.parentData">
                {{ optionObj?.ProblemId] }} - {{ optionObj?.ProblemDesc }}
            </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

**[`DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-k9wrzm?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)**